# Using Groupdate gem to make a nested grouping per day per hour

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to make an array that groups `Report` model based on the following:

```
Mon =>
   00 => 3
   05 => 5
   ...
Tue =>
   04 => 10
   08 =>3
   ...
...
```

I'm trying to use Groupdate gem for this, and while I'm able to group either by hour of day, giving me:

```
Report.created_in_last(1.year).group_by_hour_of_day(:created_at).count
00 => 3
04 => 10
05 => 5
08 => 3
```

I'm unable to also get it grouped into the days of the week. Is there a possibility to chain Groupdate commands to achieve this, or do I need to group it based on hour of the day and loop through the result set?

Thanks

Comment: Is this the gem: https://github.com/ankane/groupdate?

Comment: Yes, that';s the gem, it groups based on created_at. I'll update the code.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used [`groupdate`](https://github.com/ankane/groupdate), but from the documentation and a few guesses, here is my attempt to generate the data:

```
Report.created_in_last(1.year)
      .group_by_day_of_week(:created_at, format: '%a')
      .each_with_object({}) do |(weekday, records), out|
        out[weekday] = records.group_by_hour_of_day(:created_at).count
      end
```

Comment: I get the following PSQL error: `PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "reports.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT "reports".* FROM "reports" WHERE "reports"."deleted_a...`

Comment: I found that adding .count after the first group_by solves the error, problem is that `records` only contains the actual count, no longer the ActiveRelation, so you can't call `group_by_hour_of_day` on that

Comment: That's why i didn't add `.count` on first one.

Comment: Looks like `groupdate` gem is all about records count and not the actual records.

Comment: Yep, I'm afraid so, will solve this in plain RoR/Ruby. Thanks.